# Which method is called after post is shared on google plus(Call back method) in Android

Tags: android, share, google-plus, deep-linking

In Android App, I follwed this tutorial  :
[Share Post on google plus](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String tripDetails = "Test;
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
            .setText(tripDetails)
            .setType("image/png")
            .setContentDeepLinkId("Testing",
                    "Testing",
                    "Description.",
                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/image.png"))
            .getIntent();
    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);

}
```

It runs successfully and post is also shared on google plus.

But I don't know which method is called after Post is shared on google plus and when it returns to application back. So do you know any call back method?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: After `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`, it's called `setResult()` and `finish()`.

Comment: You have added deep-linking in your question tag. Do you mean how to handle deep linking? If not then you have to override onActivityResult method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**onActivityResult** method of your activity will be called. So handle your UI changes after posting in onActivityResult method

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities for details

Comment: can you let me now , how to show success message and prevent default success message .